# How to clone a partition to another drive on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup, partition-copy

On my computer, I have my system partition (A:), and another partition (B:) that contains all my data. Both partitions are on separate HDD.

I just want to backup B: partition without the system partition.

Is it possible to do this on windows 10 without using middleware?

I used Aomei, and I don't trust these programs.

Comment: Windows does not have the built-in feature you see.  Your only choice is to use third-party software.

Comment: You could use one partition (much more preferable) and Windows backup and/or a sync App to an external USB backup drive.

Comment: I used two partitions on different drive, because my system partition is on a 500Gb SSD, and my other partition is on a 1tb HDD.

Comment: I trust AOMEI .

Comment: 1. Read reviews of the various disk imaging tools, e.g., https://alternativeto.net/software/aomei-data-backuper/ . 2. Don't blindly trust *any* backup!! Use the app's verification tool, and then mount the disk image and examine a few files. 3. For *really* thorough protection, copy the local image to a remote location, or to the cloud. At a place where I worked, they assiduously made *daily* tape backups -- but never *verified* those. On the day they needed one, they found **all** the backup tapes were bad.  That said, *all* the disk imaging apps I've used work well.